# steroids ionic form goes below header bar

Tags: css, ionic-framework, steroids

I'm starting to play with javascript for the first time and I turned the index.html of a steroids project into a simple login form but the content is going below the header. I've also tried the `<ionic-header-bar><ionic-content>` tags but none works. What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Gestor de Mesas</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/components/ionic/css/ionic.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/application.css" />

  <script src="/javascripts/onerror.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/console.log.js"></script>

  <!-- cordova.js is served from localhost to ensure the correct version -->
  <script src="http://localhost/cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/steroids-js/steroids.js"></script>

  <script src="/javascripts/application.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="content">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
  <div class="list">

    <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Username</span>
        <input type="text">
    </label>

    <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Password</span>
        <input type="password">
    </label>
    <li class="item item-checkbox">
     <label class="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox">
     </label>
     Lembrar?
  </li>
  </div>
  <button class="button button-positive">
        Entrar
  </button>
  </ion-content>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding Class "has-header" to your  tag. It'll solve the issue. This is because :

> ion-header-bar is positioned absolutely. and hence your lower content goes behind it. **.has-header** class defines **top : 44px**, which will move your content down with the required space.